# How to handle the multiple object creation in spring row mapper classes

Tags: spring, row, mapper

```
private final ParameterizedRowMapper<ReportsVO> exportAllRowMapper = new ParameterizedRowMapper<EmployeeVO>() {
    public ReportsVO mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum)
        throws SQLException {
            try{
                EmployeeVO employeeVObject = new EmployeeVO();
                logger.debug(" exportAllRowMapper ");
                employeeVObject.setEmpid(resultSet.getString("emp_ID"));
            }
```

Above code will run 200k time atleast, so getting out of memory error because of 200k EmployeeVO  objects creation in heap memory.

Can any one suggest how to handle the object creation in spring row mapper classes?

Comment: Well of course there will be 2 lakhs of objects in memory that will be with or without a `RowMapper` as you are telling it to parse all the rows to an `EmployeeVO`. Don't load and proces all the rows. What do you want to do with all those rows?

Comment: want to import those all details into excel. so iterating 2lakhs times.

Comment: So you are converting first every row to an `EmployeeVO` and after that iterate over the full list again to export tot excel. Don't do that, the data will never fit in memory. Use a `RowCallbackHandler` and directly write the row to the excel sheet and skip the conversion to `EmployeeVO`.